# npm does not support Node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

**npm does not support Node.js v15.5.0 as well as v14.15.3**

npm Version: 5.6.0

I upgraded it trough the command: `npm i -g npm-upgrade`
But I don't get version 6, I always get version 5.6.0

I also tried different Node.js versions according to [426750](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version).

I tried following Node.js versions: v15, v14, v12, v9. It doesn't matter which Node.js version I install, i always get the samme error.

I also removed Node.js and updated it as recommended in [47226238](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47226238/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-node-js-v9-1-0), [63196042](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196042/npm-does-not-support-node-js-v12-18-3).

I have no Idea how I can fix this problem. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: In my case, solution suggested in [63196042](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63196042/4131048) worked, so deleting `npm` and `npm-cache` folder was enough. The root cause was _multiple versions of `npm` or `node` installed in different paths_ as stated in the answer below (so +1 to everyone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct command to update `npm` is `npm install -g npm`. At the time of this writing, that will install npm@6.14.10. (If it doesn't, try `npm install -g npm@6`.)

Installing `npm-upgrade` instead will install [a CLI that updates package.json in projects](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-upgrade). It will not update `npm` itself.

EDIT: The version compatibility stuff is just a warning. Based on the comment below, the `ERR! cb.apply is not a function` stuff is the real problem. You may have multiple versions of `npm` or `node` installed in different paths and your `PATH` or alias configuration is causing incompatible versions to run with each other.

EDIT (continued): If you are using `nvm` as a version manager, you can downgrade to a previous version, remove/reinstall the current version of Node.js, and you will have a compatible version of `npm`. If you are not using `nvm`, [installing it](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) (assuming you are on a development machine and not experiencing these issues in production) and using `node` and `npm` provided by it should also solve the issue.

EDIT PART 3: I just noticed you are running Node.js 15.5.0. That ships with `npm@7` so do `npm install -g npm@7`. If that doesn't work, find your executable paths for `node` and `npm`. (On UNIX-like operating systems: `command -v node` and `command -v npm`.) If they are not in the same directories, that sounds like a problem and you should investigate. It will probably be easiest/best to use the `npm` that is in the same directory as `node`. You can try that out by using the full path. If that works, figure out what's wrong with your `PATH` or your aliases that you're using a different `npm` and fix that.

Comment: thank you. I used the command `npm install -g npm` . But I still get npm verion 5.6.0. I don't undertand why it is not working. I will send the output in the next command, due the amount of characters are left.

Comment: `npm install -g npm npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v15.5.0 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ npm ERR! cb.apply is not a function  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: ... `

Comment: `npm version npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v15.5.0 npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version. npm WARN npm Supported releases of Node.js are the latest release of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9. npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/ {   npm: '5.6.0',   ares: '1.17.1',   brotli: '1.0.9',   cldr: '38.0',   icu: '68.1',   llhttp: '2.1.3',   modules: '88',   napi: '7',   nghttp2: '1.41.0',   node: '15.5.0',   openssl: .... `

Comment: Try `npm install -g npm@6`.

Comment: The version compatibility stuff is just a warning. However the `ERR! cb.apply is not a function` stuff is the real problem. You may have multiple versions of `npm` or `node` installed in different paths and your `PATH` or alias configuration is causing incompatible versions to run with each other. That's just a guess.

Answer (score -1):

[Go to the path where you can find the debug log (this file is found in your npm-cache folder) C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Roaming](https://stefvanlooveren.me/errors/npm-warn-npm-npm-does-not-support-nodejs-v14154)

Delete the NPM and NPM-Cache folder, but DO NOT reinstall node. Once deleted go back to your command line and re-use the command " npm install -g npm@latest "

[npm install --force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)